# How to get PublicKeyToken from GAC

Tags: gac, gacutil, publickeytoken

I have been following [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040%28v=office.12%29.aspx), which goes over adding a file to GAC with gacutil.

I have completed this step but I can't seem to read the Keytoken from the file.

It says to navigate to the assembly you added to the GAC, right click and view properties. How ever when I do this the PKT is mentioned no where on the properties pages.

Assume I have misinterpreted something here as no one else seems to be having this problem, where have I gone wrong? How do I view the PublickKeyToken?

### Edit: resolved.

[It's this easy.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2008/07/01/how-to-find-public-key-token-for-a-net-dll-or-assembly.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can use "sn.exe" from Visual Studio Command Prompt.

[Guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2008/07/01/how-to-find-public-key-token-for-a-net-dll-or-assembly.aspx).